# SCCM Task Sequence Conditional Registry setting check

Tags: tasks, sccm

I'm testing a conditional argument as part of my SCCM task sequence. I want to check to see if a REG_DWORD does not exist. I seem to be running into an issue where I cannot get the system to check for a REG_DWORD. It's always checking for REG_SZ and it does not give me the option for Value Type when I select "not exits". Here are the configurations.

[image: Conditionals Statement]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

I tried it like this:

[image: config1]

And like this:

[image: config2]

Both end up with the same result. In the log files I see this message:

```
Registry value HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server\Enabled of type REG_SZ does not exist
```

See how it says `REG_SZ`. So technically that's correct, a `REG_SZ` value name of "Enabled" does not exist. The problem is the "Enabled" value name is REG_DWROD, but as you can see from the screen shots if I select "not exists" then I don't get the option to select to the value type. So is there a way to check for the existence of a Value name that is a REG_DWORD?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is a bug not a feature so there is probably no way to work around with the conditions feature of the ts. So depending on what you want to execute you might have to put your check either inside a script that wraps around your installer. If this is a ts exclusive step (like apply drivers or something) where you cannot wrap, you could execute a script first, check there, write a tsvariable back and add a condition based on the tsvariable instead (kinda conplicated i know but I found a bug report that is like 18months old for this so it's probalby not fixed too soon)